# What is the utilisation level on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, scalability

How many transactions are currently executed on the Ethereum blockchain and how does this compare to other blockchains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io/charts/tx) and [etherchain.org](https://www.etherchain.org/statistics/basic), as of **1st Feb 2016**, the Ethereum blockchain is trending at ca. **15k transactions per day**.

This compares to ca. **200k transactions per day** on the Bitcoin blockchain [[source]](https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions?showDataPoints=false&timespan=all&show_header=true&daysAverageString=7&scale=0&address=).

It took approx 4 years for the Bitcoin blockchain to reach ca. 15k transactions per day since inception.

In comparison, the same ramp-up on the Ethereum blockchain took approx. 1 year.

For further comparison (non blockchain based reference points):

- Visa: 150Million transactions per day [[source]](https://usa.visa.com/run-your-business/small-business-tools/retail.html)
- Google search: 25Million queries per day in year 2000 [[source]](http://www.internetlivestats.com/google-search-statistics/), growing to 3.3Trilliom queries per day in 2012 [[source]](http://1,200,000,000,000)
- Google public DNS: 70Billion requests er day [[source]](https://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/google-public-dns-70-billion-requests.html)
- Twitter: 5k tweets per day in 2007, growing to 30Million tweets per day in 2010 [[source]](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/measuring-tweets)

Comment: One has to recognize that the path Bitcoin went is a totally different one. Before Bitcoin was nothing so bitcoin created the market and proved that such systems do not fail eventually, also it created all the awareness and the market. This is like the iPod proved that the iPhone is possible. Ethereum stands on the shoulders of Bitcoin, comparing how long they took for x is not really helpful in my opinion.

Comment: @RolandKofler: agreed. I did not include the Bitcoin figures as an indication of superiority/inferiority on either side. My intent was to add a reference point as otherwise "15 transactions per day" can be rather meaningless. I have now added a few more reference points with the aim to put the scale into further perspective.